# Why do few teams use "hybrid" starters other than the Tampa Bay Rays?

Tags: mlb, pitching

The Tampa Bay Rays traded Chris Archer for pitcher [Tyler Glasnow](http://www.espn.com/mlb/player/_/id/33190/tyler-glasnow) (and two other prospects).

The Rays have then "started" Glasnow in four games, for 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, and 6.2 innings, respectively. He is regarded as a powerful hurler with a good strikeout rate, but more of a long reliever than a true starter. Yet the Rays have used him in a "hybrid" role, with the hope of eventually developing a starter. In two of these games, other starters, Jake Faria, and Ryan Yarborough "relieved" Glasnow, and picked upt the wins.

The Pirates actually had three potential starters of this type: Glasnow, Chad Kuhl (now injured), and Steve Brault? Why not have a "fifth starter by committee" e.g. have Glasnow, Kuhl and Brault start on the 5th, 10th, and 15th day of a cycle, with the other two as backups during those games?

The Pirates are actually fairly good at turning long relievers into starters. [Jos Musgrove,](http://www.espn.com/mlb/player/_/id/34848/joe-musgrove) acquired in exchange from the Astros for Gerrit Cole is a case in point, and in an earlier era, James McDonald. But for whatever reason, they did not do so with Glasnow using a "piecemeal" approach, and the Tampa Bay Rays did.

What might Tampa Bay do this, not others, including the Pittsburgh Pirates?

Comment: Why do you claim that Glasnow is "... more of a long reliever than a true starter"? He went through the minor leagues as a starter and initially the Pirates tried him as one. Unfortunately for the Pirates, he was poor as a starter with them (there seem to be issues with how the Pirates told him to pitch, but that's getting off topic). At that point, they resorted to using Glasnow as a reliever. Also, Tampa has returned him to a starting role and has not yet had him pitch in relief; If he's pitching longer each game, it seems they are trying to turn him (back) into a conventional starter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that starters train to pitch once a week and relievers train to pitch whenever they are called into action, which could be anytime.

This article dives into this: http://www.sportingnews.com/au/mlb/news/pitchers-who-are-starters-and-relievers-mike-montgomery-mike-minor-cubs-rangers/aj436r7wiyzg12gvsk80bjsr7

> The challenge for so-called hybrid pitchers ... [is having]
>   to take care of their bodies in a way that keeps them on the
>   mound, which is not easy because training to pitch once a week is
>   quite different from training under the possibility of pitching on any
>   given day.

Answer (score 1):

When I began following the game (mid-1970's), it seemed fairly common for at least a couple pitchers on a roster to relieve some and start some. Sure, there were guys who were used strictly as starters and others who were strictly relievers. However - and especially for early career pitchers, middling pitchers, and guys coming back from injury - there were pitchers who did both.

Since then, it seems a viewpoint has developed throughout the major leagues that specialization - or having a role - is the best way for most players to be used. Along the same lines, closers are rarely used outside of a save situation in the 9th inning (and the most common exceptions to that seem to be save situations in extra innings, or perhaps bring him in for the the 4 or 5 out save in the 8th inning). This viewpoint has somewhat extended to position players - especially starters - but doesn't seem quite as prevalent there - yet.